# Xcode 7 error GIT authentication failed

Tags: git, xcode7

When trying to push git repository, I get error with the username and password, but in version Xcode 6.4 never had this problem.

[image: error repo]

Comment: user and password are correct, but not in xcode7

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in Xcode.  You can get around it by changing the address to include your username, e.g.,

```
http://victor@192.168.1.33/...
```

Then enter your password normally.

Comment: does not work since I took the test and nothing from the terminal but the Keychain fail me, I have to put the login data again

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I use the Source Tree replace  it.